# Some inserts are not appearing in DB table

Tags: java, java-8, persistence, oracle12c, executorservice

I am trying to insert the records after reading them from a file. There are bunch of files, I read/parse one file at a time and insert all the records from that file at a time. This works fine in most cases, but I have noticed, there is one file which has 879 records which are not getting inserted or not appearing in DB table. The same code works fine, if I remove or add any 1 record from the file. DB is Oracle 12c.
The file whose records are not inserted is not throwing any error.
Can anybody please point out what could cause such a behavior?

This is how the code looks like..

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
List<CompletableFuture<Void>> completableFutures = 
     pnlFiles.stream().map(pnlFileForTheBook ->    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            String pnlFileName = "";
            String cobDate = "";
            String filePath = "";
            try {
                File localPnlFile = nasDataLoader.downloadFile(pnlFileForTheBook, filePath);
                if(localPnlFile != null) {
                    List<PnlFile> pnlFileLines = parse(localPnlFile, PnlFile.class);
                    List<PnlFileDsl> pnlFileDsls = pnlFileLines.stream().map(line -> {
                        return new PnlFileDsl(line, cobDate);
                    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
                    persistenceManager.persist(pnlFileDsls);
                }
            } 
              catch () {} 
           }, executorService)).collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<Void> result = completableFutures.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join)
                                                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The same code works with all other files, the file whose records are not appearing has no issues.

Comment: Maybe you did check, but is it really not throwing any exception? Since your sample has syntax error and does not handle exception in any way. Problem could be also with parsing given file but we do not know since you do not show us the file (at least sample), do not specify format and do not show parsing method. Did you debug it? What parsing returned for erroneous file?